# Python Pandas Lambda: Using multiple variables Lambda within DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a Series such as follow:

```
example = pd.Series([[1.0, 1209.75, 1207.25],
 [1.0, 1211.0, 1207.5],
 [-1.0, 1211.25, 1205.75],
 [0, 1207.25, 1206.0],
 [1.0, 1206.25, 1201.0],
 [-1.0, 1205.75, 1202.75],
 [0, 1205.5, 1203.75]])
```

This Series has basically a list of 3 numbers in each cell.
I turn it into a DataFrame and add a new column:

```
example = example.to_frame(name="input")
example["result"]=np.NaN
```

Now i would like to perform the following operation on it:

```
example["result"] = example["input"].apply(lambda x,y,z: y if x==1 else z if x==-1 else NaN)
```

I receive the following error message when trying to do it: 
`missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'z'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lambda only takes one argument which in this case is a list. Simply index the list:

```
>>> example["result"] = example["input"].apply(lambda lst: lst[1] if lst[0]==1 else lst[2] if lst[0]==-1 else np.NaN)
>>> example
                      input   result
0   [1.0, 1209.75, 1207.25]  1209.75
1     [1.0, 1211.0, 1207.5]  1211.00
2  [-1.0, 1211.25, 1205.75]  1205.75
3      [0, 1207.25, 1206.0]      NaN
4    [1.0, 1206.25, 1201.0]  1206.25
5  [-1.0, 1205.75, 1202.75]  1202.75
6      [0, 1205.5, 1203.75]      NaN
```

On a lighter note, you could refactor the nested ternary operators into a function with nested ifs, so your code is more readable:

```
def func(lst):
    x, y, z = lst
    if x == 1:
        return y
    elif x == -1:
        return z
    else:
        return np.NaN


example["result"] = example["input"].apply(func)
```

Comment: Yes I found it too just now... Sorry guys. But funny how very often wording my question is enough for me to find the answer... Anyway, thanks!
What do you mean with your comment? What would be your suggestion?

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the case of the function, why are we using x, y, z instead of x[0], x[1], x[2] as in the lambda? Are function and lambdas not supposed to be equivalent?

Comment: I'm passing `lst` as the parameter, not `x`. Just a change of name

Comment: Ok yes I had missed that one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized solution:

```
In [30]: example
Out[30]:
                      input
0   [1.0, 1209.75, 1207.25]
1     [1.0, 1211.0, 1207.5]
2  [-1.0, 1211.25, 1205.75]
3      [0, 1207.25, 1206.0]
4    [1.0, 1206.25, 1201.0]
5  [-1.0, 1205.75, 1202.75]
6      [0, 1205.5, 1203.75]

In [31]: example['result'] = np.where(np.isclose(example.input.str[0], 1),
    ...:                              example.input.str[1],
    ...:                              np.where(np.isclose(example.input.str[0], -1),
    ...:                                       example.input.str[2],
    ...:                                       np.nan))
    ...:

In [32]: example
Out[32]:
                      input   result
0   [1.0, 1209.75, 1207.25]  1209.75
1     [1.0, 1211.0, 1207.5]  1211.00
2  [-1.0, 1211.25, 1205.75]  1205.75
3      [0, 1207.25, 1206.0]      NaN
4    [1.0, 1206.25, 1201.0]  1206.25
5  [-1.0, 1205.75, 1202.75]  1202.75
6      [0, 1205.5, 1203.75]      NaN
```

Comment: This does not handle the case where `example.str[0]` is -1

Comment: @MaxU This is interesting except for the .isclose  that is a bit unfortunate

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, thank you for pointing it out! I've corrected my answer

Comment: @jimbasquiat, when using `float` dtype it's [better to compare values using `isclose` or `allclose`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python)